# How Do I use plasma-widget-wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, widgets

I am trying to use the plasma-widget-wifi widget to monitor my wifi connecions. I installed it but now have no clue how to to put it on my desktop, I am using 12.04 lts. Anyone know how to do this?

I find it hard to believe no one on this site knows how to install widgets. If no one has an answer can you at least tell me where I can find information regarding my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on desktop.It will give you an option `Add widget`
- Click on it and it will open a pane at the bottom of your screen
  containing all your widget.
- From here you an add a widget by double clicking a widget.

Comment: I was asking this question when i was logged into my laptop. Now I am on my desktop which has 64 bit 13.04 on it. What is the procedure for 13.04?

Comment: If you have installed `kde-plasma-desktop`, you can use above method when you running plasma-desktop on your desktop.

Comment: ahh ok, i was trying it on the default unity. I will have to try installing that thank you.